# Is there shortcuts for dot net like php asrtisan

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am moving from php-laravel to .net core 2.2
in php-laravel you can write in terminal :

> `php asrtisan make:auth`

and it will create immediately tables, controllers and authentications 
is there anything like that in .net core 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net core doesn't have that, but you can try with [Identity package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Just go through docs and it's nothing complicated to add it to your project.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you , and is there any general name for things other than login and authentications ?? i have found something to use like package manager :: Update-Database, if there is a name for that hope i know..thank you again

Comment: `Update-Database` will update your database from your context and migrations. So you need to include Identity in your context and startup. You can check how to install packages with [package manager console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell). If this helped you please mark it as answer and upvote it, Thanks. :)